# how to add a new condition in table rate shipping

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.8

Here is problem i am facing, if any one know this please help me, i am working on magento 1.8

in table rate shipping there is three conditions.

```
>>Weight vs. Destination
>>Price vs. Destination
>># of Items vs. Destination
```

### my question is how can i add more 1 in it.

I want an own create attribute value vs Destination here , and i want to calculate shipping with help of this

So any one did this please help me.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Magento weight vs destination table rate shipping costs example**

[how to edit this one or setting for](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping)

```
Here is an example of weight vs destination pricing for UK

Country,Region/State,"Zip/Postal Code","Weight (and above)","Shipping Price"

GBR,*,,1000.0000,75.0000
GBR,*,,65.0000,50.5000
GBR,*,,50.0000,40.0000
GBR,*,,40.0000,30.0000
GBR,*,,30.0000,20.0000
GBR,*,,20.0000,17.0000
GBR,*,,10.0000,9.7500

This example has different weight based shipping costs for the UK.
```

[Setting Up Table Rate Shipping](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-table-rate-shipping)

```
The table rate shipping method lets you calculate shipping rates for a combination of conditions using data that you can edit. The shipping rate can be based on the following calculations:

    Weight v. Destination
    Price v. Destination
    # of Items v. Destination
```